# How to update/set a field dynamically in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm working on a project where I have to create a database and update specific field in the schema. That field name is coming to me dynamically in an object.

```
                Logs.find({username:user.username}, (err,docs) => {
                docs.map(d => {
                    var startTime = new Date(2000, 0, 1,  8, 0);
                    var loginTime = new Date(2000, 0, 1,  hours, minutes);
                    if (loginTime < startTime) {
                        loginTime.setDate(loginTime.getDate() + 1);
                    }

                    var sessions = loginTime - startTime
                    sessions = parseInt((sessions/60000)/15) + 1

                    if(d.date == exactDate){
                        WFHsessions.findOneAndUpdate({username:d.username,date:exactDate},{
                            sessions:true
                        })
                    } else {
                        const NewSession = new WFHsessions({
                            username:d.username,
                            sessions:true
                        })

                    }
                })
            })`
```

Here, I have to set sessions value in WFHsessions schema. Actual field name is a number (1,2,3...) and that number is stored in sessions variable.How do I update that specific field using this variable. If i'm writing sessions variable as it is, it will look for a field named "sessions" in my schema which doesnt exist. 
How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub document.
basically store your sessions in an array of objects

Comment: I am not able to use array in mogoDB, I tried defining array of objects in schema but when I push the object, the array in my collection doesn't know any further fields.

Comment: can you share to me your current shema if you dont mind